# Can Accepted Answer be changed if the OP is not 'visiting' the site anymore?

Tags: support

I recently added an answer to an old question for which I think the accepted answer is incorrect, but the OP has not returned to the site for the last couple years. **Is there any way to get the Accepted Answer changed (to the correct one)?** Do I flag it for moderator attention?

It seems wrong that an inactive user can "own" the Accepted flag such that it cannot be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything to add to [this answer by Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80321):

> The "accepted answer" feature was never intended to mark which answer is best or even if the answer is correct. It is, simply stated, the answer that the original author found most useful in solving their problem.
>
> The people's-choice favorite answer is selected through the voting process. The "accepted answer" is all the original author. If you want to let the users also select the "accepted answer", the purpose of having a selected answer becomes redundant and useless. That decision has to come from the author, or you're just conflating the two features.

Comment: "Politics as usual" I guess. Maybe we should add a "Correct Answer" indication as well? Should I downvote answers that are incorrect, even years later? I am often dumbfounded that correct answers don't arise in this forum, but it is basically random who sees what and what gets dealt with at any given time. Many monkeys typing at keyboards, producing an encyclopedia.

Comment: any specific examples?

Comment: @nocomprende If the community isn't voting to your liking, who are you appointing to add this "correct answer" indicator? Labeling this issue *politics as usual* or *monkeys typing at keyboards* seems a bit insulting considering that your solution to label anything you chose as categorically correct by fiat. I'm just saying.